# Access function present in dynamically added javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding some javascript files. Then I need to use functions present in them. In firebug's `Scripts` tab, I can see that the scripts are added. Function `LoadScript1Function` is present in one script and `LoadScript2Function` in other. 
But the error i'm getting is:

```
`ReferenceError: LoadScript1Function is not defined`
```

Here's my code:

```
function LoadScripts(){
    try{
        var allScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        for (var x = 0; x < jsPaths.length; x++) {
            if($.inArray(jsPaths[x], allScripts) == -1){
                loadScript(jsPaths[x], null);
            } 
        }

        async(LoadScript1Function, function(){ ; });
        async(LoadScript2Function, function(){ ; });
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

// Load script
function loadScript(url, callback){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

// Async call
function async(fn, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        fn();
        callback();
    }, 0);
}
```

Tried following as per `adeneo`'s suggestion. But not working.

```
loadScript(jsPaths[x], function(){ 
     if(jsPaths[x].indexOf('Script1') != -1){ // script name check in the path
         LoadScript1Function();
     }
});
```

Comment: There's a callback in your loadScript function for when the script has loaded, why not use it instead of passing null ?

Comment: If the `LoadScript1Function` is defined globally or attached to something accessible from `window`, your code should work.

Comment: Looking more carefully at the code, I don't really get it? The script tags are already on the page, you're getting them with getElementsByTagName and then you're passing them to that strange loadScript function which creates new script tags that are the same as the ones you're getting, so now you're loading all your scripts twice? Why are you doing this ?

Comment: Then you have some strange notion that just using a deferred funtion with a zero timeout will wait for the duplicate script tags to load, but a zero timeout will be executed when the thread is available, there's no guarantee that your scripts will be loaded, especially if they are async ?

Comment: @adeneo, `jsPaths` has some js paths to load. `$.inArray(jsPaths[x], allScripts) == -1` will be true if js file with current path is not present in the page. Then I'm adding the that js file to the page.

Comment: Well, as a sidenote jQuery has a $.getScript method that seems useful to  you ?

Comment: @adeneo, ok, I was not aware of such function.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a problem in your `setTimeout` call - the timeout is `0`. Javascript is generally single-threaded and can lock up other components of the browser, so that a timeout of 0 won't let anything be downloaded. You have to increase those milliseconds and also check if the script is already operable; if not, schedule a new timeout. Although I can't see how is that async function needed in the first place.

What I like to do in similar cases is trying to access a property or function that is supplied by the thing and then waiting some more if it fails.

What I don't like about callbacks is that you have to go on the railroad prepared by the platform developers quite narrowly and any little extra demand for flexibility derails your whole code. Using the setTimeout for everything may be better after all. You could then handle "dropped connections" fast, update any throbbers/progress bars, anything.